# Socket Communication Python with Multithreaded & Multi-client to Multi-Server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client, python-multithreading

I am new in Python socket communication. I have a problem about multi client & multithreading. I am using SocketTest3 app for server. I open 4 "SocketTest3" programs. They all work on localhost but the port entries are different. Later, the threads I created open my clients. There is no problem so far. But my client threads are opened in order. Problem started right there. I want these threads to start at the same time. Because if the client at the top of the queue fails to connect to a server, my code explodes before my other clients are allowed to connect. Can you help me about that topic ? My clients code is;

```
import socket
import threading
from threading import Thread
import time
import os

class ClientSockets(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip_1, port_1, ip_2, port_2, ip_3, port_3, ip_4, port_4):

        self.ip_1 = ip_1
        self.port_1 = port_1

        self.ip_2 = ip_2
        self.port_2 = port_2

        self.ip_3 = ip_3
        self.port_3 = port_3

        self.ip_4 = ip_4
        self.port_4 = port_4

        self.start1Condition = True
        self.start2Condition = True
        self.start3Condition = True
        self.start4Condition = True

        try:
            #Creating Socket-Clients
            self.socketClient1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            
            self.socketClient2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            self.socketClient3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            self.socketClient4 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            
            #Connection Validation
            self.socketClient1.connect((self.ip_1, self.port_1))
            print("1.Client connected..")

            self.socketClient2.connect((self.ip_2, self.port_2))
            print("2.Client connected..")
            
            self.socketClient3.connect((self.ip_3, self.port_3))
            print("3.Client connected..")

            self.socketClient4.connect((self.ip_4, self.port_4))
            print("4.Client connected..")

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

        #Control to Threads
        self.clientThread_1 = Thread(target=self.start_1)
        print("Thread-1 created..")
        self.clientThread_2 = Thread(target=self.start_2)
        print("Thread-2 created..")
        self.clientThread_3 = Thread(target=self.start_3)
        print("Thread-3 created..")
        self.clientThread_4 = Thread(target=self.start_4)
        print("Thread-4 created..")



    def start_1(self):

        
        try:
            while self.start1Condition:

                self.yanit1 = self.socketClient1.recv(4096)
                print(self.port_1,":",self.yanit1.decode())
                
    
            self.clientThread_1.close()

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    def send1(self, msg):
        self.socketClient1.sendall(msg.encode())   

    def start_2(self):

        
        try:
            while self.start2Condition:

                self.yanit2 = self.socketClient2.recv(4096)
                print(self.port_2,":",self.yanit2.decode())
                
            self.clientThread_2.close()

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
    
    def send2(self, msg):
        self.socketClient2.sendall(msg.encode())

    def start_3(self):

        try:
            while self.start3Condition:

                self.yanit3 = self.socketClient3.recv(4096)
                print(self.port_3,":",self.yanit3.decode())
                
            self.clientThread_3.close()

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
        
    def send3(self, msg):
        self.socketClient3.sendall(msg.encode())    

    def start_4(self):

        try:
            while self.start4Condition:

                self.yanit4 = self.socketClient4.recv(4096)
                print(self.port_4,":",self.yanit4.decode())
                
            self.clientThread_4.close()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    def send4(self, msg):
        self.socketClient4.sendall(msg.encode())


    def run(self):
        self.clientThread_1.start()
        self.clientThread_2.start()
        self.clientThread_3.start()
        self.clientThread_4.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runz = ClientSockets("localhost",8787,"localhost",8788,"localhost",8789,"localhost",8790)
    runz.run()
```

When I don't start "8787", which is the first port to connect from the Sockettest3 program, my code stops working before it starts.

Best Regards..

Comment: Have you tried wrapping each client connect into its own try-except? Since you have them all in the same, if 1 fails, naturally it won't get to 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: @user3832673 I moved the client connections from __init__ into each client methods and the problem was solved.  Now I can connect other clients even if the port of the first client is not active. Thank you for advise.